# Entity enhancement on maven module jar. Entity classes are not found

Tags: class, maven, module, entity, ebean

I'm having a Maven Project (Project A), executing operations of a Maven Module (ProjectB), in which my entity classes are defined.

Enhancement goes well when I build ProjectB alone and run it's own unit tests (they all pass).

When I compile ProjectA, in which test operations are exactly the same as in ProjectB, the entity classes can not be found, even with ProjectB.jar searched for them.

However, if I make Project B a Maven Project instead of a Maven Module. Everything goes well, entity classes are found in ProjectB.jar and tests pass.

Can please somebody tell me what's going on?

EDIT (please find enclosed this diagram for the layout of my project)

https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/3803648/3922814/c93638b4-23cd-11e4-8bea-5de01bb3930a.jpg

(I have to have at least 10 rep points to enclose an image directly into the post. sorry)

Comment: Don't understand the reason for a down vote here. clearly shows some effort although a folder layout would have been helpful. but that doesn't warrant a down vote, a simple comment should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I don't think you need to duplicate the unit tests at the project level when they are already part of the module. If you run mvn install at either modlue level or th eproject level, the tests classes will get executed.

So basically a "module" and "project" are the same thing but when you have a module defined it needs a Parent project and any operation you do on the Parent gets applied to all modules that is part of the Parent.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

The duplicated test case was just to simplify the problem description. Think of ProjectB as Domain Layer, and Project A as a Service Layer, hence the intention is to have tests placed in a high abstraction layer in ProjectA that use domain methods of ProjectB.

I know about the dependency inheritance and operation propagation from parent to it's modules. 

Somehow, if I make ProjectB a Maven Project instead of a Maven Module, it works and the tests pass.

What am I missing, someone?

Comment: Parent projects usually are used as aggregators and the packaging type would be "pom". So a Service layer(Project A) with source code shouldn't be a project of type "pom". So in your case I would suggest to change the project structure slightly such that, you have a Parent project of type "pom" -> add two modules-> Project A and Project B. Now add a dependency for Project B in Project A's pom. And add your test cases under Project A. I am pretty sure with this setup you could have test cases under Project A(service layer) and Project B still can be a module. HTH

Comment: Hello again. I added a reference to an image that depicts the layout of my project. It is exactly like the one you described. Parent has packaging type "pom" and both PA and PB modules type "jar". Except that I have those duplicated tests. The tests I have on PB are irrelevant, as they are run again in PA. It is just to show you how weird it is, that they work fine if executed inside the package, and explode when they use PB's jar.